# Tex4ebook - incorrect chapter/appendix order

Tags: tex4ebook

Running Tex4ebook on this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\end{document}
```

results in an [Epub](https://mega.co.nz/#!KNkxnITY!TYgKXzYPe6T3WQfkzverq2NVhQ17J6ulKnkZIoKXHjE) with the appendix preceding the first chapter.

Is this a known issue? Is it possible to get the correct order without manual editing of the epub?

Installation detail

- Tex4ebook (commit 9a8319, Wed Feb 4)
- Arch, TexLive 20150411 64-bit (scheme minimal)
- Installed via tlmgr: latex latex-bin amsmath babel carlisle ec geometry grahics hyperref lm  marvosym oberdiek parskip pdftex-def urllisle ec geometry graph fancyhdr listings tex4ht etoolbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because all chapters are extracted to standalone html files by tex4ebook, which is recommended practice for ebooks, because of memory and computing constraints of ebook devices. But appendices were kept in the main html file, which resulted in that they appeared before all extracted chapters.

I hope I've fixed that in the `tex4ebook` sources now, so appendices should be extracted as well. Please download the current `tex4ebook` version.

Note that you will get blank first page of your ebook if you extract everything to standalone files, you may use at least `\maketitle` to put something to the main file.